# understanding the basic concepts in memory organisation and applying those effectively in solving questions

Tags: caching, memory-management, ram, processor

(well, actually proceeding to the question, I want to confess that this is a homework question, please do consider it and help me in improving my understanding a bit more.)

I have recently started learning computer organisation and architecture. I have gained fair understanding for how caches are organised, how mapping between cache and main memory takes place (direct , fully and set-associative mapping), what is a page table(what are pages, blocks etc.), i can that say I have basic knowledge of segmentation , paging, virtual address and physical addresses.( at the basic level ofcourse).

well I have come across this question:

```
A computer has 46-bit virtual address ,32- bit physical address, and a three level 
page table organisation. The page table base-register stores the base address of the 
first level table(t1), which occupies exactly one page.Each entry of t1 stores the base 
address of the page of second level table t2. Each entry of t2 stores the base address
of the page of the third level table t3. Each entry of t3 stores a page table entry 
(PTE). The PTE is 32 bit in size. The processor used in the computer has a 1MB 
16-way set associative virtually indexed physically tagged cache. The cache block size
is 64 Bytes.
```

First of all I am facing difficulty in just imagining such type of a virtual computer.
can any one help me by giving a simple steps on How to realize such a virtual computer on paper, or just how to understand what is given in the question. What is really asked??
How would one represent a computer having a 46-bit virtual address and having three level page table.

```
what is virtually indexed and physically tagged cache.
```

After reading what is given above , I feel that I just know the terms but I am unable to relate them together to solve problems.
I will be glad If someone tries to explain how my thought process should be understand and apply these concepts practically to solve such types of problems.

some questions based on the above paragraph:

```
 1) What is the size of a page in KB in this computer?


 2) what is the minimum number of page colours needed to guarantee that no two synonyms 
    map to different sets in the processor cache of this computer?
```

A good resource where such problems are actually taught to solve will a appreciated.
Good articles and views are most welcome.

Thankyou in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

We know that all levels page tables must be completely full except outermost, outermost page table may occupy whole page or less. But in question it is given that Outermost page table occupy whole page.

Now let page size is 2 Bytes.

Given that PTE = 32 bits = 4 Bytes = 2<sup>2</sup>  Bytes.

Number of entries in any page of any pagetable =page size/PTE = 2<sup>p</sup>/2<sup>2</sup> = 2<sup>p-2</sup>.

Therefore Logical address split is

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|-------------|
|      p-2            |      p-2         |       p-2           |     p       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|-------------|
```

logical address space is 46bits given.

Hence equation becomes,

(p-2)+(p-2)+(p-2)+p = 46

⇒p=13.

There fore page size is 2<sup>13</sup> Bytes =**8KB**.

Answer (score -1):

I can help you with the first question.

Let page size is 2^x. Each entry of T1 is 32 bits means 4 bytes. Total size is 2^X bytes(1 page). T1 contains 2^X  / 4 = 2^(X-2) entries.
So we use first X-2 bits of the 46 bit virtual address to index into one entry in T1. It gives the address of one T2.

T2 also contains 2^(X-2) entries.( same way as T1). So we use next X-2 bits to index into T2 and get the address of a T3.

It is given each entry of T3 is 32 bytes (including flags and all). Total size of 1 page = 2^X bytes. No of entries is 2^(X-2). So again we use X-2 bits to index into T3 and get the staring adress of frame.

Then we need the offset. Since the page size is 2^X, offset is X bits long.

First (x-2) bits gives address of T2.

Next (x-2) bits gives address of T3.

Next (x-2) bits gives address of Frame from T3.

Remaining x bits give offset in frame.

Total is 46 bits

x-2  +  x-2  +  x-2  +   X        = 46

4X - 6 = 46

X =13

Page Size = 2^13 bytes.